# How do I obtain Fine Alcrysts?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I want to craft more Magic Keys, but although the other ingredient (Screamroot) is available from several quests as a potential drop, there is no location given for farming fine alcrysts.

Is the only choice to get them thru King Mog events etc., or are they farmable after advancing the story past a certain point? (or any other way, such as the Vortex missions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Fine_Alcryst) page, aside from King Mog event, you can obtain Fine Alcrysts by

> **Crafting**
>
> 20% chance to obtain one after crafting any ability ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/FFBraveExvius/comments/4pf49o/data_required_post_the_number_of_fine_alcryst_you/)).
>
> **Trophies**
>
> Silver for Fabled Smith, Divine Technician, and Peerless Chemist.
>
> **Reward**
>
> (Event) [Lunar New Year](https://exvius.gamepedia.com/Lunar_New_Year) - Nian Beast Challenges! - INT (Day 5)